# 2GP Managed Package: Admin Profile changes

Tags: managed-package, system-admin, second-generation-packaging

Is it possible to package and ship permission modifications to the `System Administrator` profile in a `Managed Package` or not?

If not, am I right in assuming permissions should be shipped as a `Permissions Set` or custom `Profile`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I do not recommend using Custom Profiles in managed package (except if you are distributing the app as OEM app) as it requires a Mapping during installation which is an additional step that admins may miss.

Permission sets are easier to build and manage.

You can find some best practice here:

- [Permission Sets and Profile Settings in Packages](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=distribution_perm_sets_profile_settings.htm&type=0)

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't modify the `System Administrator` profile.

Yes, custom Profile or Permission Set for managing the perms your package needs.